# PHP - Load data from file with format X=Y

Tags: php, ini

I have a file without any format called `.env`.

All the values are stored like this: `X=Y`

My supervisor told me to load this data into my PHP script, I need the values as array.
He said I can do it because the file is build like an ini file. But there are no sections.

I tried it like this:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("../../.env");    // Output: false
$data = include("../../.env");                // Output: 1 -> prints the content of the file into the document
```

---

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:WVS0jXq4FBEOHEt2+K3AxyLCvTgq5L/dMhiFd5HZg7Q=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://api-konfigurator.local

JWT_SECRET=5PdNYddJuntDfbErQBg0vnUwwNCJiDy8hc1QMNAFaAWsdKJv2fe6m3ueLbYdYOk3

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=x
DB_USERNAME=y
DB_PASSWORD=z
```

Comment: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv Use this library, pretty standard for any PHP project

Comment: What do you mean "without format"? Data is clearly formatted.

Comment: I mean files with no specified file format

Comment: [The format](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#what-rules-does-the-parsing-engine-follow) is pretty specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fairly straightforward to parse a file in the format mentioned but complicated slightly by some lines potentially including multiple `=` signs, such as for `APP_KEY`

That said, perhaps the following might help.

```
$filepath='c:/temp/fakeini.txt';


$data=array();
$lines=file( $filepath, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
foreach( $lines as $index => $line ){
    if( !empty( $line ) ){
        $count=substr_count( $line, '=' );
        if( $count > 1 ){
            $pos=strpos($line,'=');
            $param=substr($line,0,$pos);
            $value=substr($line,$pos+1);
        }else{
            list( $param, $value )=explode( '=', trim( $line ) );
        }
        $data[ $param ]=$value;
    }
}
```

which yields an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [APP_NAME] => Laravel
    [APP_ENV] => local
    [APP_KEY] => base64:WVS0jXq4FBEOHEt2+K3AxyLCvTgq5L/dMhiFd5HZg7Q=
    [APP_DEBUG] => true
    [APP_URL] => http://api-konfigurator.local
    [JWT_SECRET] => 5PdNYddJuntDfbErQBg0vnUwwNCJiDy8hc1QMNAFaAWsdKJv2fe6m3ueLbYdYOk3
    [LOG_CHANNEL] => stack
    [DB_CONNECTION] => mysql
    [DB_HOST] => localhost
    [DB_PORT] => 3306
    [DB_DATABASE] => x
    [DB_USERNAME] => y
    [DB_PASSWORD] => z
)
```

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius This is a working code but fragile, so I do not recommend to use it in production. How about `NAME="the name"`?  It is better to use ready libraries or simply export ENVs and [read it from OS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

Comment: What's the point of using special case for more than 2 `=`s? That special case can also handle a single `=`. Or you can just set the limit argument on `explode` to 2.